# Go Lang Workspace Duplicate Package Name Executable Collision

Tags: go, namespaces, package

If following the GoLang documentation for workspace structure it is possible that two executable packages will share the same package name.

For example, there are two packages from github:

```
$ $GOPATH/src/github.com/alpha/import
$ $GOPATH/src/github.com/beta/import
```

The `import` package from user `alpha` is first installed:

```
$ go install github.com/alpha/import
```

The binary executable is now available in `$GOPATH/bin` and is named `import`.

Then the second package from user `beta` is installed:

```
$ go install github.com/beta/import
```

This install/build will replace the existing `import` binary from user `alpha` with the `import` binary from user `beta`.

A better naming convention could avoid this collision; however, is there a standard practice for fixing this issue when using third party libraries?

Answer (score 3):

This collision happens only for executables and *never* for packages. Executables are much less common and often have distinguishing names so in practice I never encountered this problem.

The "fix" or "best practice" is obvious and dead simple: Just rename the binary after installing.

Comment: You might also mention specifying output name: `go build -o myexename`.